# @Bean vs @Autowired cyclic dependency

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jackson

I came across a strange behaviour with respect to `@Bean` and `@Autowired` in my `@Configuration` class. My web project structure is like
Controller → Service → Repository

In my Service I have a dependency on `ObjectMapper`

```
@Autowired
  public ServiceClass(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
  }
```

Since I want to use a Java 8 optional class while deserializing, I wanted to register `Jdk8Module`. So I created a configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

@Bean
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    return objectMapper;
  }
}
```

I initially thought that Spring will inject the objectMapper instance which it has, which I can manipulate and return it, so that when I autowire it in my service class, I get the updated instance of ObjectMapper.

But I get a cyclic dependency error. This is understandable because, my bean configuration depends on objectmapper and returns an objectmapper.

But it is surprising, if I change the method to have `@Autowired` instead of `@Bean`, Spring doesn't complain and works as expected.

```
@Autowired
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    return objectMapper;
  }
```

Why is that?

Comment: That is why you should us a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` instead of this contraption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Bean` annotation goal is to provide beans from the Spring BeanFactory. When a method is annotated `@Bean`, it is supposed to return a new instance of an object. It can use paramaters if Spring is able to instantiate them too.

In your example, when you declare

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
  objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
  return objectMapper;
}
```

It means your `ObjectMapper` is a bean (of course) that takes a parameter which is an instance of `ObjectMapper` and Spring knows `ObjectMapper` so it can instantiate it using... the very same method. Here is your cyclic dependency.

In the case of `@Autowired`, Spring uses an `ObjectMapper` as a parameter of your method that is already in the `BeanFactory`. That's why it removes the cyclic dependency.

I hope I'm clear enough.

Little reference here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html

Comment: Please don't put reference to an old, out-dated and unmaintained piece of code. Instead link to the proper Spring java based configuration docs (part of the regular Spring documentation).

Comment: Yes it was a so old reference ! But as the page gave the right info I didn't check (shame). It's updated now.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
@Autowired
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
  objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
  return objectMapper;
}
```

Someone else is injecting an ObjectMapper (maybe Spring) to this method. I think the Autowired annotation is not necessary in this case, Spring knows you want to inject a bean here.

You aren't creating new beans in this case so you will not have a cyclic dependency error here.

If you want to create a new one, maybe you should play with @Qualifier.

More info: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-configuration-and